# R download,file freeze

Tags: r, download, freeze

I'm trying to download some images from a website. I have a series of `urls` of images that I have to download. So I run it with this code :

```
 dlphoto <- function(x){
   print(x)
   setTimeLimit(5)
   Sys.sleep(0.3)
   download.file(x , destfile = basename(x))
   }
```

This function has however one major problem : 
When I run my vector of 15000 `urls` with it, it freezes the entire R session, and stop reacting to anything. However, if I run `urls` separately, it works fine. Or when I run for example 1:50 `urls`, it works too. However, when I put 1:100, for example, it freezes as well.... So can you please help me to figure this out ?

at first I was using this line to call:

```
 dlphoto(allimage[,2])
```

then I changed to this one :

```
 dlphoto(allimage[c(1:50),2])
 dlphoto(allimage[c(51:100),2])
 dlphoto(allimage[c(101:150),2])
 dlphoto(allimage[c(151:200),2])
 and so on untill 15000
```

and so on. But it still freeze a lot. And each time it dies I have to close R and search where the process reached and start from there. And I get this warning message regularly :

```
   Error in download.file(x, destfile = basename(x)) : 
   reached CPU time limit
```

And also, can you help me to make that the photos downloaded are saved in

```
    /Users/name/Desktop/M2/Mémoire M2/Scrapingtest/photos
```

thanks a lot !!

Comment: How are you calling function`dlphoto` to download 15000 urls? Please add that code as well.

Comment: thanks for reminding. Just added the precision to the question.

Comment: You can very easily prevent the error message by removing the useless `setTimeLimit` call in your function. Also, remove the `Sys.sleep`: it’s likewise not useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of improvements possible. I have assumed that `OP` is using `download.file` from `base` packages which supports only single file in one attempt if `method` is not set `libcurl` and `quiet = T`.

Hence the fix should be to use `method = "libcurl"` and `quiet = TRUE` in `download.file` function. The changed function:

```
dlphoto <- function(x){
    print(x)
    download.file(x , destfile = basename(x), method="libcurl", quiet = TRUE)
}
```

OR

```
download.file(x , destfile = basename(x), method="libcurl", quiet = TRUE)
```

**Note:** In both above cases, the progress-bar will not be displayed.

I think the value of `timeout` from `options` is good enough to ensure return from `download.file` in case of delays.

The error for return value from `download.file` should be checked. Any `non-zero` return value indicate failure.

If you want to see progress-bars (which is probably not needed for 1500 files in one go) then function should be modified to handle 1 file at a time. The modified function will be:

```
# This function will display progressbar for each file
dlphoto <- function(x){
  for(file in x){
    print(fine)
    download.file(file , destfile = basename(file))
  }
}
```